# How can I get curl -w output (invoked by xargs) onto separate lines?

Tags: linux, shell, curl, xargs, seq

I am trying to split the lines that I get from the following command but it's not being split at new line. How to do it?

```
seq 0 1 5000 | xargs -n 5 -I{} -P 5 -- curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}" "http://somewebsite.com/{}.txt" >> result.txt
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use `xargs` at all here?

Comment: Yes it is... parallel processing.

Comment: You're using `-P 1`. That turns off parallelism altogether.

Comment: Also, `-0` doesn't make sense, since your input from `seq` is newline-delimited.

Comment: Ah I forgot to update it. :)

Comment: Using the output from `xargs -P` is dangerous due to race conditions. See example on https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#DIFFERENCES-BETWEEN-xargs-AND-GNU-Parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `\n` in your format string if you want each result to be on its own line:

```
-w '%{http_code} %{url_effective}\n'
```